# Validation Users Issues

Tags: 7, commerce, installation, http-request

I have my fresh web site up and running. My first test is to try the functionality of creating a new user.  I tested added myself (no, not my admin account -- a different one with a different email address).  The new user's (mine) email got an alert saying that the account would be approved by the admin and further instructions and password would be sent to me.

I got the alert email also at the admin email address and I logged on and assigned the account a password and approved the account.

But the new user's email never got the notification.  I also tried to find the user's email address by using the admin's privileges on the site in case I needed to deliver the message to the user by hand.  But I could not find out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.  The problem was that one has to look in the "spam" folder to see email that is sent by automated means.